# Exchange Master Master cluster switch client

Tags: windows, exchange

I have take over the management of a master-master exchange cluster.

Exchange Server 2010
Version: 14.01.0438.000

The second master is currently syncing mailboxes but it is not used for sending out mail. I have to switch over all clients from the current master which is also the domain controller to the second exchange server.

I have noticed that when an exchange server is configured in Outlook I cannot add a second one so in order to test the second server I would have to remove my current exchange account but even if I would readd a new one it would most likely connect to the current domain master.

How can I connect to the second exchange for test and how can I switch over the domain later on that all clients are using the second exchange server?

Once again this is NOT a new setup, neither an upgrade. This is an operating master-master exchange cluster where I want to switch all the clients on the LAN to use the second active master instead of the first one (which is also the main PDC).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken installing Exchange on a DC isn't supported or at least discouraged. Move one of the accounts to the new server and you should be able to connect to it. You're not really switching a domain but to make them use a different server you'd have to adjust the configuration (GPO, DNS or whatever else you're using to make them use the current server). You lack a lot of detail what you got in place and what you really want to do.

Comment: Whether it is discouraged by Microsoft or not this is the way it was setup and as I said this is a master-master setup already replicated, I don't have to move any mailboxes because they exist on the 2nd server already I just need to test this and then switch over the whole domain to use the secondary. Detail is the 2 servers are Windows 2008 R2 Standards, maybe this is why it is still allowed for the PDC to be the main exchange.

Comment: So you already know everything? Well than just do what you need to do to make it work. Alternatively open a ticket with Microsoft. For instance Exchange doesn't have a "domain master" so your original question is lacking. If you're unwilling to provide details, you will likely need to look for other sources of support. Also my remark about changing client configuration changes still applies - which you ignored. If you're looking to change something about your clients you will have to include information about their setup.

Answer (score 0):

Do you deploy a new DC or Exchange server in current Exchange environment?
If it's a new Exchange server and the mailbox is moved to this new server, the Outlook client would be working fine, and we don't need to re-configure Outlook profile.

Maybe, end user will get a notification to re-start Outlook client to take effect after mailbox moving.

Which Exchange version are you used now?